# why does split method stop working with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, split, tkinter-entry

Whenever I run this code with the `chopped = first_word.split()` line I get an error (the window closes instantly).

```
import tkinter as tk

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Conversation")
win.iconbitmap("cake.ico")
win.geometry("600x700")
#Lists
Hellos = ["greetings", 'hello', 'greetings', 'hi']
gday = ['good', 'great', 'incredible', 'not bad', 'okay']
bday = ['bad', 'awful', 'not the best', 'terrible']

fw_label = tk.Label(win, text="Hello user, it's nice to meet you.")
fw_label.pack()
first_word = tk.Entry()
first_word.pack()
chopped = first_word.split()
```

But when I change the line `first_word = tk.Entry()` to `first_word="A normal string"` , the split method highlights and when I hover it it gives its description, which wasn't happening with ```first_word = tk.Entry()``.

*I've ran into this problem when using libraries like opencv, may I know what's causing it not to work?*

Comment: Is `first_word` supposed to be an entry widget, or a string?

Comment: You have a larger problem here.  Remember that tk is an event-driven system.  Nothing will be displayed until you do `win.mainloop()`.  When you call `tk.Entry()`, that just asks for a box to be created.  It won't be created and drawn until the mainloop can process the events.  You need to have a button for the user to say "OK, I have finished typing", and only in the callback for that button will there be anything inside the entry box for you to fetch.

Comment: You're calling `split` on a widget, not on the contents of the widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is simple. You have to make a function to be called while pressing the submit button. And the statement `chopped = first_word.get().split()` should be inside that function.

Coming to the error part, it was because `first_word` is a tkinter `entry` object without any attribute `split()`.
The split method works only for strings. To get the text entered into the entry widget in form of string, you need to use the `get()` method...

```
import tkinter as tk

def click():
    chopped = first_word.get().split()
    print(chopped)

win = tk.Tk()
win.title("Conversation")
# win.iconbitmap("cake.ico")
win.geometry("600x700")
#Lists
Hellos = ["greetings", 'hello', 'greetings', 'hi']
gday = ['good', 'great', 'incredible', 'not bad', 'okay']
bday = ['bad', 'awful', 'not the best', 'terrible']

fw_label = tk.Label(win, text="Hello user, it's nice to meet you.")
fw_label.pack()
first_word = tk.Entry()
first_word.pack()
tk.Button(win, text="Submit", command=click).pack()

win.mainloop()
```

So, you get the text of the entry using the `get()` method and then split it

Note : The statement `chopped = first_word.get().split()` should be inside the function because if its outside it, it would be executed at the time of the creation of the entry widget and using `get()` there would result in an empty value as the entry doesn't contain anything at that point

Comment: @Tree-log please mark it as accepted if it worked, so other people having similar issue get their solution fast

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could work

Change

```
chopped = first_word.split()
```

to

```
chopped = first_word.get().split()
```

Comment: This is true, BUT at the time he executes this function, the box hasn't been displayed yet, so there won't be anything to fetch.

Comment: @Maleh This won't work as the line will be executed when the box is not created and yould return empty string as the widget would not contain anything

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reply my comment on your last question because of my low reputation. `https://www.shapedivider.app/`  here you would easily make the curves you want and embed the code to your project. I use this often.

Comment: Thank you so much, that website is really helpful, hope you have a good day.